# Mega Menu Javascript create delay on deactivate_action

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I am using the JQuery MegaMenu version 2 from www.geektantra.com, http://www.geektantra.com/2010/05/jquery-megamenu-2/

I am trying to set a timeout when the mouse is not hovering the menu. So when your mouse is in the menu moving around as soon as you move the mouse off the menu it closes the menu. I want it to wait three seconds before dissapearing.

The `mm_timeout` in options did not do anything. The `options.mm_timeout = 0;` for `activate_action` works to delay the load of the menu but there isn't anything for `deactivate_action`. 
The `slideUp` method can be changed to slow but it only waits less then a second. I'm new to JQuery, thank you

This is the jquery.megamenu.js file:

```
/*
jQuery MegaMenu Plugin
Author: GeekTantra
Author URI: http://www.geektantra.com
*/
var isIE6 = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie 6') != -1;

jQuery.fn.megamenu = function(options) {
options = jQuery.extend({
                          activate_action: "mouseover",
                          deactivate_action: "mouseleave",
                          show_method: "slideDown",
                          hide_method: "slideUp",
                          justify: "left",
                          enable_js_shadow: true,
                          shadow_size: 3,
                          mm_timeout: 250
                      }, options);
var $megamenu_object = this;
if( options.activate_action == "click" ) options.mm_timeout = 0;
$megamenu_object.children("li").each(function(){
jQuery(this).addClass("mm-item");
jQuery(".mm-item").css({ 'float': options.justify });

jQuery(this).find("div:first").addClass("mm-item-content");
jQuery(this).find("a:first").addClass("mm-item-link");
var $mm_item_content = jQuery(this).find(".mm-item-content");
var $mm_item_link = jQuery(this).find(".mm-item-link");
$mm_item_content.hide();

jQuery(document).bind("click", function(){
  jQuery(".mm-item-content").hide();
  jQuery(".mm-item-link").removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
});
jQuery(this).bind("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
  $mm_item_content.wrapInner('<div class="mm-content-base"></div>');
if(options.enable_js_shadow == true) {
  $mm_item_content.append('<div class="mm-js-shadow"></div>');
}
var $mm_timer = 0;
// Activation Method Starts
jQuery(this).bind(options.activate_action, function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var mm_item_link_obj = jQuery(this).find("a.mm-item-link");
  var mm_item_content_obj = jQuery(this).find("div.mm-item-content");
  clearTimeout($mm_timer);
  $mm_timer = setTimeout(function(){ //Emulate HoverIntent
    mm_item_link_obj.addClass("mm-item-link-hover");
    mm_item_content_obj.css({
      'top': ($mm_item_link.offset().top + $mm_item_link.outerHeight()) - 1 +"px",
      'left': ($mm_item_link.offset().left) - 5 + 'px'
    })

    if(options.justify == "left"){
      var mm_object_right_end = $megamenu_object.offset().left + $megamenu_object.outerWidth();
                                // Coordinates of the right end of the megamenu object
      var mm_content_right_end = $mm_item_link.offset().left + $mm_item_content.outerWidth() - 5 ;
                                // Coordinates of the right end of the megamenu content
      if( mm_content_right_end >= mm_object_right_end ) { // Menu content exceeding the outer box
        mm_item_content_obj.css({
          'left': ($mm_item_link.offset().left - (mm_content_right_end - mm_object_right_end)) - 2 + 'px'
        }); // Limit megamenu inside the outer box
      }
    } else if( options.justify == "right" ) {
      var mm_object_left_end = $megamenu_object.offset().left;
                                // Coordinates of the left end of the megamenu object
      var mm_content_left_end = $mm_item_link.offset().left - mm_item_content_obj.outerWidth() + 
                                $mm_item_link.outerWidth() + 5;
                                // Coordinates of the left end of the megamenu content
      if( mm_content_left_end <= mm_object_left_end ) { // Menu content exceeding the outer box
        mm_item_content_obj.css({
          'left': mm_object_left_end + 2 + 'px'
        }); // Limit megamenu inside the outer box
      } else {
        mm_item_content_obj.css({
          'left': mm_content_left_end + 'px'
        }); // Limit megamenu inside the outer box
      }
    }
    if(options.enable_js_shadow == true) {
      mm_item_content_obj.find(".mm-js-shadow").height( mm_item_content_obj.height() );
      mm_item_content_obj.find(".mm-js-shadow").width( mm_item_content_obj.width() );
      mm_item_content_obj.find(".mm-js-shadow").css({
        'top': (options.shadow_size) + (isIE6 ? 2 : 0) + "px",
        'left': (options.shadow_size) + (isIE6 ? 2 : 0) + "px",
        'opacity': 0.5
      });
    }
    switch(options.show_method) {
      case "simple":
            mm_item_content_obj.show();
            break;
      case "slideDown":
            mm_item_content_obj.height("auto");
            mm_item_content_obj.slideDown('fast');
            break;
      case "fadeIn":
            mm_item_content_obj.fadeTo('fast', 1);
            break;
      default:
            mm_item_content_obj.each( options.show_method );
            break;
    }
  }, options.mm_timeout);
});
// Activation Method Ends
// Deactivation Method Starts
jQuery(this).bind(options.deactivate_action, function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  clearTimeout($mm_timer);
  var mm_item_link_obj = jQuery(this).find("a.mm-item-link");
  var mm_item_content_obj = jQuery(this).find("div.mm-item-content");
//      mm_item_content_obj.stop();
  switch(options.hide_method) {
    case "simple":
          mm_item_content_obj.hide(); 
          mm_item_link_obj.removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
          break;
    case "slideUp":
          mm_item_content_obj.slideUp( 'fast',  function() {
            mm_item_link_obj.removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
          });
          break;
    case "fadeOut":
          mm_item_content_obj.fadeOut( 'fast', function() {
            mm_item_link_obj.removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
          });
          break;
    default:
          mm_item_content_obj.each( options.hide_method );
          mm_item_link_obj.removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
          break;
  }
  if(mm_item_content_obj.length < 1) mm_item_link_obj.removeClass("mm-item-link-hover");
});
//    Deactivation Method Ends
});
 this.find(">li:last").after('<li class="clear-fix"></li>');
 this.show();
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an option `mm_hide_timeout: 250` and use it when it is time to hide the menu (`$mm_hide_timer` variable should be added to plugin as well):

```
$mm_hide_timer = setTimeout(function(){
    //...hiding functionality
}, options.mm_hide_timeout);
```

Activate plugin in this way:

`$(".megamenu").megamenu({mm_hide_timeout: 1000});`

Here is the full [<kbd>**demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/hAacW/)

Comment: What is the difference between the $mm_hide_timer: 250 and the mm_hide_timeout: 1000 ?

Comment: `var $mm_hide_timer = 0;` is a variable used for holding numerical ID of the timer, which could be started by [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout). `mm_hide_timeout` is an option for plugin, it is used as a second parameter to setTimeout(), which hides the menu. See the demo at line **18** (adding an option), **122 - 147** (starting a timer).

Comment: Okay, now I noticed that if I hover off the menu before it goes away and hover back onto the menu the menu still goes away anyway. Is there a way to stop it from hiding if I hover back onto it before it dissappears?

Comment: Yes, when I changed my menu as your code it didn't work. I don't need the last line to activate it and in order to set the time I had to make line 23 have the time. I am using the click option, jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".megamenu").megamenu({ 'activate_action':'click' });
// Can take 'click', 'mouseover' and 'mouseenter' as values only. Default: 'mouseover'
});

Comment: You have JavaScript error on your page: `Object #<Object> has no method 'tabs' Line:1013: $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");`. Is my fiddle working for you?

Comment: Yes, the tabs is for the table below. Ignore that error because the tab table still works. I am only working in the header menu that say Products  Support  etc. Its okay, your help was great, +1